# Java regex matches but String.replaceAll() doesn't replace matching substrings

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

```
public class test {
        public static void main(String[]args) {
            String test1 = "N&oslash;rrebro, Denmark";
            String test2 = "&oslash;";
            String regex = new String("^&\\S*;$");
            String value = test1.replaceAll(regex,"");
            System.out.println(test2.matches(regex));
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

This gives me following Output:

```
true
N&oslash;rrebro, Denmark
```

How is that possible ? Why does replaceAll() not register a match?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Your `value` comes from replacing **test1**, while your `matches` is testing **test2**.

Comment: Yes, but test2 is a substring of test1. test2 also matches with the regex.
From my understanding replaceAll() looks for substrings that  match a regex and replaces them with a given replacement.

Comment: **Only** `test2` matches with regex. `test1` does not.

Comment: Your `test2` matches the regex, but only if it's a whole string and not a substring. Check what `$` means at the end of a regex...

Comment: What is the difference between a substring and a whole string ?

Comment: You don't seem to realise that you're using anchors in your regex. Putting `^` at the beginning means that the regex starts from the very beginning of the string. And `$` means that it goes to the end. So yes, `test2` matches because of the anchors, but `test1` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible because `^&\S*;$` pattern matches the entire `&oslash;` string but it does not match entire `N&oslash;rrebro, Denmark` string. The `^` matches (requires here) start of string to be right before `&` and `$` requires the `;` to appear right at the end of the string.

Just removing the `^` and `$` *anchors* may not work, because `\S*` is a greedy pattern, and it may overmatch, e.g. in `N&oslash;rrebro;`.

You may use `&\w+;` or `&\S+?;` pattern, e.g.:

```
String test1 = "N&oslash;rrebro, Denmark";
String regex = "&\\w+;";
String value = test1.replaceAll(regex,"");
System.out.println(value); // => Nrrebro, Denmark
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/dkI6kk).

The `&\w+;` pattern matches a `&`, then any 1+ word chars, and then `;`, anywhere inside the string. `\S*?` matches any 0+ chars other than whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex includes `^`. Which makes the regex match from the very start.

If you try

```
test1.matches(regex)
```

you will get `false`.

Comment: I need the "&" character to be at the beginning. Shouldnt it match a substring that starts with "&" ?

Comment: @StefanWatt In your `test1` string, `&` is not at the beginning, it is after `N`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand what `^` and `$` means.

You probably put them in there because you want to say:

> At the **start** of each match, I want a `&`, then 0 or more non-whitespace characters, then a `;` at the **end** of the match.

However, `^` and `$` doesn't mean the start and end of each *match*. It means the start and end of the *string*.

So you should remove the `^` and `$` from your regex:

```
String regex = "&\\S*;";
```

Now it outputs:

```
true
Nrrebro, Denmark
```

"What character specifies the start and end of the *match* then?" you might ask. Well, since your regex basically the pattern you are matching, the start of the regex *is* the start of the match (unless you have lookbehinds)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex : `&(.*?);`

```
        String test1 = "N&oslash;rrebro, Denmark";
        String test2 = "&oslash;";
        String regex = new String("&(.*?);");
        String value = test1.replaceAll(regex,"");
        System.out.println(test2.matches(regex));
        System.out.println(value);
```

output :

```
true 
Nrrebro, Denmark
```